# AttributeError: 'ImageList' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, fast-ai, machine-learning-model

Am trying to run this cell:

```
test = ImageList.from_df(test, img_path, suffix='.jpg')
 data.add_test(test)
```

And getting this error

> 

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_22/2201896868.py in <module>
----> 1 test = ImageList.from_df(test, img_path, suffix='.jpg')
      2 data.add_test(test)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/vision/data.py in from_df(cls, df, path, cols, folder, suffix, **kwargs)
    283         "Get the filenames in `cols` of `df` with `folder` in front of them, `suffix` at the end."
    284         suffix = suffix or ''
--> 285         res = super().from_df(df, path=path, cols=cols, **kwargs)
    286         pref = f'{res.path}{os.path.sep}'
    287         if folder is not None: pref += f'{folder}{os.path.sep}'

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/data_block.py in from_df(cls, df, path, cols, processor, **kwargs)
    134     def from_df(cls, df:DataFrame, path:PathOrStr='.', cols:IntsOrStrs=0, processor:PreProcessors=None, **kwargs)->'ItemList':
    135         "Create an `ItemList` in `path` from the inputs in the `cols` of `df`."
--> 136         inputs = df.iloc[:,df_names_to_idx(cols, df)]
    137         assert not inputs.isna().any().any(), f"You have NaN values in column(s) {cols} of your dataframe, please fix it."
    138         items = _maybe_squeeze(inputs.values) if len(df) > 1 else (inputs.values[0] if not isinstance(cols, Collection) or len(cols) == 1 else inputs.values)

AttributeError: 'ImageList' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

Any help?

Am trying to merge test and train data

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like ImageList.from_df() expects a pandas.DataFrame, but you are giving it an ImageList.

You can check with

```
type(test)
```